# array called peopleTypes that can store a maximum of 50 integer values. enter a series of 1,2,3,4 and output how many of each number was inputed

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class People
{
    public static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static final int Max= 50;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int index;
            int check;
            int infants = 0, children = 0, teens = 0, adults = 0;
            System.out.println("Please enter value:");
            int [] peopleTypes = new int[Max];

            for(index=0; index<Max; index++)
                {
                    peopleTypes[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if(peopleTypes[index] == 1)
                        infants = infants + 1;
                    if(peopleTypes[index] == 2)
                        children = children + 1;
                    if(peopleTypes[index] == 3)
                        teens = teens + 1;
                    if(peopleTypes[index] == 4)
                        adults = adults + 1;
                    else
                        index = index-1;
                    System.out.print("");
                }
```

So basically I have to create a code that allows a user to input 50 values (1,2,3,4) into a array and count how many of each was inputted and outputs that. I am stuck on creating the code to count the inputted values. I am new to array and am not sure if I'm on the right path.

Comment: Which part of this is giving you trouble? What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: to count the 1,2,3,4 from the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to store the input, take a (closer) look at a possible solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class People {
   static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   static final int MAX = 50;
   static final String[] LABLES = {"infants", "children", "teens", "adults"};

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] counts = new int[4];
       for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
           System.out.println("Please enter value:");
           int current = keyboard.nextInt(); //problem input: "abc" -> java.util.InputMismatchException
           while (current > 4 || current < 1) {//checks range
               System.out.println("Please enter a valid value (between 1 and 4):");                    
               current = keyboard.nextInt();//...and repeat
           }
           counts[current - 1]++;//increment counter, "current - 1", since 0-based array and 1-based input
       }
       System.out.println("Evaluation finished!");
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {//print the output
           System.out.println(LABLES[i] + ": " + counts[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe misunderstanding the context but I do not see the need for creating a peopleTypesArray. My understanding is that all you need is a count or teens , adults etc from a list of 50 people, so just keep incrementing the individual counters and display them outside the loop. Something like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 50; i++){
   int peopleType = keyBoard.nextInt();
   if(peopleType == 0){
      infantCount++; 
   }  
   ---- and so on
}  

System.ou.println(" infant =  " + infantCount);
 --- and so on
```